# Python - append reference in a list

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

After executing the following code,

```
my_list = []
v = 1
my_list.append(v)
v = 2
print(my_list)
```

the result is

```
[1]
```

I think this happens because "v" is appended by value, not by reference. Is there anyway to pass it by reference on appending, so that result can be 2?

Comment: Python does not support references to variables. You can only have references to objects. `v = 2` rebinds `v` to refer to a new object; this will never affect the list's reference.

Comment: You will need to use a different reference type than integer for it to be mutable. Integers are immutable, and for that, they are appended by value. It would need to be an object, like a list if you want a simple python object, or your own predefined object.